# How to apply haversine formula to a set of coordinates

Tags: python, coordinates, distance

I need to calculate distance for a set of coordinates. I have the function for calculating it but I don't know how to use it on my data.

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
  lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
  dlon = lon2 - lon1 
  dlat = lat2 - lat1 
  a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
  c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
  r = 6371
  return c * r
```

What I did so far was to transform the columns to lists:

```
lat1= frame['Start Station Lat'].values.tolist()
long1= frame['Start Station Long'].values.tolist()
long2=frame['End Station Long'].values.tolist()
lat1= frame['End Station Lat'].values.tolist()
```

Then I tried to use apply() function:

```
frame['distance_travelled'] = frame.apply(lambda lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2: haversine(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2), axis=1)
```

But it has not worked. Please advise!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, this might help; using the apply function on a frame gives you access to the values of a row, meaning you dont need to convert the columns to lists. So for your example case you could do:

```
frame['distance_travelled'] = frame.apply(lambda x: haversine(x['Start Station Lat'],x['Start Station Long'],x['End Station Long'],x['End Station Lat']), axis=1)
```

Also just in case, you have 2x lat1 as a variable name:

```
lat1 = frame['Start Station Lat'].values.tolist() ###HERE
long1= frame['Start Station Long'].values.tolist()
long2=frame['End Station Long'].values.tolist()
lat1= frame ['End Station Lat'].values.tolist() ###HERE
```